Gaussian and mean curvature formulas proof from definition
I have the following exposition in my notes about the principal and Gauss curvatures:
Principal curvatures
Recall that the shape operator $s$ is a self-adjoint linear endomorphism of the tangent space $T_pM$ (or generally, any such operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$). Consider the smooth map
$$
f(v) := \langle s v, v \rangle.
$$
On the compact set $C = \{v : q(v) := \langle v, v \rangle = 1 \}$, the maximum is achieved for some $v_0 \in C$. By the Lagrange multiplier rule, there is a real number $\lambda_0$ such that $df = \lambda_0 dq$, hence by linearity and self-adjointness of $s$, it follows that for all $w \in V$,
$$
\langle s v_0, w \rangle = \lambda_0 \langle v_0, w \rangle,
$$
and thus all such maximal $v_0$ are $s$-eigenvectors with real eigenvalues $\lambda_0$ due to the nondegeneracy of the inner product. Consider $b_1 = v_0$ to be the first unit basis vector, and set $B := \text{span}\{b_1\}$. Clearly, $s(B) \subseteq B$, and thus by self-adjointness $s(B^\perp) \subseteq B^\perp$. We can apply induction to obtain the following result.
Proposition 6.24 (Finite-Dimensional Spectral Theorem)
Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space and $s: V \to V$ is a self-adjoint linear endomorphism. Then $V$ has an orthonormal basis of $s$-eigenvectors, and all eigenvalues are real.
Suppose $(M, g)$ is a Riemannian hypersurface of a Riemannian manifold $(\widetilde{M}, \widetilde{g})$ and $p \in M$. Then the shape operator $s: T_pM \to T_pM$ has real eigenvalues $\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_n$, and there is an orthonormal basis $(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ for $T_pM$ consisting of $s$-eigenvectors with
$$
s b_i = \kappa_i b_i, \quad i = 1, \ldots, n.
$$
Hence $s$ (and $h$) are in this basis represented by diagonal matrices, and thus
$$
h(v, w) = \langle s v, w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \kappa_i v^i w^i.
$$
Definition
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian hypersurface of a Riemannian manifold $(\widetilde{M}, \widetilde{g})$. The eigenvalues of the shape operator $s$ at a point $p \in M$ are called the principal curvatures of $M$ at $p$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are called the principal directions.
Definition
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian hypersurface of an $(n + 1)$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(\widetilde{M}, \widetilde{g})$. The Gaussian curvature is defined as
$$
K := \det(s),
$$
and the mean curvature as
$$
H := \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{tr}(s) = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{tr}(h).
$$
Since the determinant and trace of a linear endomorphism are independent of the basis, they are well-defined for a chosen unit normal. In terms of the principal curvatures,
$$
K = \kappa_1 \kappa_2 \cdots \kappa_n, \quad H = \frac{1}{n} (\kappa_1 + \cdots + \kappa_n). \tag{*}
$$
Exercise
Prove the formulas (*) for the mean and Gaussian curvature. Do these quantities depend on the choice of normal vector $N$? If yes, how?
My question is about this exercise I am suspicious about it. It looks like there is nothing to prove. The only thing would be to write trace and determinant as sum and product of the eigenvalues of $s$, which is exactly $(*)$. Is this really all I need to do to prove $(*)$ or am I missing something?
Therefore my solution would be the following:
The Gaussian curvature is defined as $K = \det(s)$. Since the shape operator $s$ is represented in an orthonormal basis $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ by a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \dots, \kappa_n$, its determinant is the product of these eigenvalues:
$$
K = \kappa_1 \kappa_2 \cdots \kappa_n.
$$
The mean curvature is defined as $H = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{tr}(s)$. The trace of $s$ is the sum of its eigenvalues, so:
$$
H = \frac{1}{n} (\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \cdots + \kappa_n).
$$
Both $K$ and $H$ depend on the choice of the unit normal vector $N$. If $N$ is replaced by $-N$, the shape operator $s$ changes sign: $s \to -s$. For $K$, the determinant satisfies $\det(-s) = (-1)^n \det(s)$, so:

If $n$ is even, $K$ remains unchanged.
If $n$ is odd, $K$ changes sign.

For $H$, the trace satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(-s) = -\operatorname{tr}(s)$, so:
$$
H \to -H
$$
when $N$ is replaced by $-N$. Thus, $H$ always changes sign under this transformation.

Looks fine to me. Not a very deep exercise.

@TedShifrin Thank you, indeed it looked so trivial, I though I was missing something
